# How to append a list into a specific index of a .txt file in python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
indexing = []
old_list = []
base = 1
code = int(input("Which flight to edit: "))
count = int(code) - base
indexing.append(count)

with open('schedule.txt', 'r') as file:
    for position, line in enumerate(file):
        if position in indexing:
            line = line.strip()
            data = [line.replace("[", "").replace("]", ",").replace(" ", "").split(',')]
            old_list = data
            print("The selected flight to modify is:\n", data[0])

            while True:
                old_data = str(input("\nData to edit: ")).upper()
                if old_data in data[0]:
                    new_data = str(input("New data: ")).upper()
                    for i in range(len(data[0])):
                        if data[0][i] == old_data:
                            data[0][i] = new_data
                    print("The updated list is: ", data[0])

                    break
                else:
                    print("Data not found, Please re-enter")
                    continue
try:
    with open('schedule.txt', 'a') as file:
        line = ','.join(data[0])
        for line[0] in data[0]:
            file.write(line)
            file.close()
except TypeError:
    pass
```

This is the content of my schedule.txt file:

```
[1] MH371, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, BEIJING , 19-12-2021, N/A
[2] SX849, AIRASIA          , KUALA LUMPUR, BANGKOK , 05-01-2022, N/A
[3] MH234, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, LANGKAWI, 03-02-2022, N/A
[4] FD709, KOREA AIRLINE    , KUALA LUMPUR, SEOUL   , 29-12-2021, N/A
[5] Z1314, CATHAY AIRLINE   , KUALA LUMPUR, TOKYO   , 21-01-2022, N/A
[6] HY520, EMIRATES         , KUALA LUMPUR, TAIPEI  , 15-11-2021, N/A
[7] TT879, MALINDO AIR      , KUALA LUMPUR, HAWAII  , 08-02-2022, N/A
```

My current code doesn't replace the specific line in .txt file I want to replace. I want to know is there a way to append my list to a specific line in .txt file without assigning index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#read all the data
with open('schedule.txt') as infile:
    data = infile.read().splitlines()

#display the data and get the flight to edit
print("\n".join(data))
code = int(input("Which flight to edit: "))-1

#ignore the line number within []
index, details = data[code].split("] ")
print("The selected flight to modify is:\n", details)

#get the updated data
old_data = input("\nData to edit: ").upper()
new_data = input("\nNew data: ").upper()

#construct the new line
new_line = index+"] "+", ".join(new_data if word.strip()==old_data else word for word in details.split(", "))

#keep all data except new_line unchanged
output = data[:code]+[new_line]+data[code+1:]

#write back to file
with open('schedule.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
```